# Get directly string from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a text field and i want to process the entry after clicking on submit.

The text field is:

`<%= text_field :reason_message, params[:reason_message] , placeholder: "Write a reason" %>`

The form is:

`<%= form_tag main_admin_controller_path, :method => 'post' do %>`

And the submit tag is:

`<%= submit_tag "Send", name: 'send', data: { disable_with: "Loading..." },class:  'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>`

To get the entry I take the parameters as:
`params["reason_message"]`
which is returning an array `["test"]` or if nothing is written `[""]`.

How can I get the params directly as a string and not as an array?

Right now I do `params["reason_message"].join` to get it as a string. Is there another way?

Comment: Ca you show us the form?

Comment: Do you have another control named `:reason_message`?

Comment: No, this is the only one

Comment: Instead of describing your code please show us the actual code involved so that we know what is actually going on and so that we can actually reproduce the issue. Relevant information here is the form, the controller and a log that shows the request parameters. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It could be because you have square brackets in your 2nd argument to `text_field`. Instead of 
`<%= text_field :reason_message, params[:reason_message] , placeholder: "Write a reason" %>`, Perhaps try something like:

 `<%= text_field :reason_message, :reason_message , placeholder: "Write a reason" %>`